# PowerQuery to Excel sorting

Tags: excel, sorting, powerquery

How do I force an Excel table to keep the same sorting I've applied in Power Query?

I have loaded a data model query from an access database file, which I have then shaped and sorted using Power Query.
Afterwards I have imported it as an Excel table using the "Existing Connections" and made sure that I have the "Preserve column sort/filter/layout" box checked.

However, the data I see in Excel is not sorted and seems to be thrown in completely at random?

I have also checked the "Preserve column sort/filter/layout" box in the "Design - Table tools" under external connections?

Comment: Preserve column sort/filter/layout means it's preserving the sorting on the table in Excel, not the sorting from Power Query. Try unchecking that option and see if it works?

Comment: That's the default setting, which didn't work either. That's why I tried using the preserve column sort/filter/layout feature, but to no avail :/

Answer (score 0):

I usually just add an index column in PQ and resort in Excel after linking to the existing connection. 
The same issue happens in reverse when you bring sorted data into PQ, and it resorts it without being asked. An index column in the initial table import solves that as well

Comment: So far I've just made a macro to sort it, which works as a work around. It just seems like a really weird limitation from Microsofts part. Why would you even give Power Query the option to sort columns if Excel doesn't recognize it anyway? It just seems pointless.